# How to use multer upload file without middleware

Tags: node.js, express, multer, express-validator

I'm new to NodeJS, I'm developing app where I have created registeration form. To upload images, I'm using **multer**. And for form validation I'm using **express-validator**. The issue with me is that, before form validation, file has upload. So, if user hasn't created account because of some validation errors, but file goes upload. The problem is that I get file upload for each form submition no matter, account has successfully created or not.

What I want to do?

I want save file only when user has successfully created account. So, is there anyway to use multer inside callback, so when my form validations are done, then files goes upload. I can't use **express-validation** middleware between **multer** midleware and final callback, because **express-validation** passes it's errors to next call back.
Here is my some code

```
router.post('/registeration', multerMiddleware, validationMiddleware, finalCallback)
```

**validationMiddleware** is an array.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var multerMiddleware= multer({dest: './profile-images', fileFilter: userRegisteration.fileFilter}).single('profileImage');
var validationMiddleware = [check(...), check(...),...]
var finalCallback = function (req, res, next) {
 // code is here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Express router executes the middlewares in the same sequence you mount
>   them

```
router.post('/registeration', multerMiddleware, validationMiddleware, finalCallback)
```

So, your `multerMiddleware` is executed ( and hence saved the file ) before your `validationMiddleware` has done the validation.

Change the code to:

```
router.post('/registeration', validationMiddleware,multerMiddleware, finalCallback)
```

So, `multerMiddleware` will only save file once the request is validated

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but then I can't access validation messages in finalCallback which validationMiddleware passes to it's next callback because of multerMiddleware between them

Comment: Move the multer middleware last in the sequence. And you'll have validation messages in finalCallback

Comment: When either I move or remove multerMiddleware, then I can't done validations, all validations error appear. I don't know why. I have tried this 
      router.post('/registeration', validationMiddleware, validationfinalizeand thenNext ,multerMiddleware, finalCallback)
Here validations check is not in finalCallback, so as I have moved multerMiddleware my all errors will appear

Comment: This error comes because of this **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form tag of html